# Are there good reasons to use the `extern` linkage specifier in new code?

Tags: c++, header-files, extern, linkage

Recently I have seen code similar to this:

foo.cpp:

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct Foo { /* some code */ };

std::unique_ptr<Foo> makeFoo() { return std::make_unique<Foo>(); }
// No other instantiation of Foo whatsoever in this file
```

bar.cpp:

```cpp
extern std::unique_ptr<Foo> makeFoo();

void someFunc() {
  auto myFoo = makeFoo();
  // ...
}
```

As you can see, `Foo` as such would not require a factory function like `makeFoo()`, but because no header declaration is provided (and there is no such thing as `extern class Foo;`), it is still needed to instantiate `Foo` in other translation units (TUs).

This leads me to the following (related) questions:

- Why would one want to write such code? Is there any benefit in this particular case over just splitting `Foo` into header/source or can I consider this an antipattern? The intention is to instantiate `Foo` in other TUs anyway.
- When writing *new* code (i.e. no need to access other people's code with `extern`), why would one want to use `extern` anyway? In my view, unless technical reasons apply, `extern` leads to convoluted and less maintainable code. In particular I'd be interested in any advantages over header files.

*Note that I am referring to ***linkage specifiers*** here, not to [other usages of the keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/extern) such as `extern template`).*

Comment: For function declarations? No. For variable declarations? It's mandatory or it's a definition.

Comment: I am voting to reopen. The linked question does _not_ answer my question. I am not asking about the usage of `extern` in a header file (I'm aware that functions have external linkage by default), but asking about possible benefits of `extern` in the shown example.

Comment: This question really has the scent of any answer being an opinion. My 2¢ opinion is that writing this, rather than using a header file is intending on this being the *only* use of that function outside of it's translation unit, and not polluting the header file with this, as the header file is the 'agreed ' API.